# Adding a jQuery script to the Django admin interface

Tags: jquery, python, django, admin

I'm gonna slightly simplify the situation. Let's say I've got a model called Lab.

```
from django.db import models

class Lab(models.Model):
    acronym = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    query = models.TextField()
```

The field `query` is nearly always the same as the field `acronym`. Thus, I'd like the `query` field to  be automatically filled in after entering text in the `acronym` field in the Django admin interface. This task must be performed by a jQuery script.

So if I take an example: you want to add a new lab to the database through the Django admin interface. You click the add button and you land on the empty form with the two fields. You manually fill in the `acronym` field with a value such as `ABCD` and then the `query` field should antomatically be completed with the same value, that means `ABCD`.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To add media to the admin you can simply add it to the meta class Media of your admin class, e.g.:

**admin.py**

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # regular stuff
    class Media:
        js = (
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
            'js/myscript.js',       # project static folder
            'app/js/myscript.js',   # app static folder
        )

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Mind the trailing comma if you only have one file included, as it has to be a tuple. You can also opt in css this way.

The admin already has (an older version) of jquery included. To shortcut it for usage add this to the top of the 'myscript' file:

```
if (!$) {
    $ = django.jQuery;
}
```

To solve your problem, I would [extend the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls). You can add a js event to any DOM node to trigger an ajax call in your myscript file to the correct admin view for handling.

Comment: This may have changed since it's an old question, but as of Django 1.8.1, the css is specified as a dictionary with the key being the target media and the value being the tuple of paths as above. Use comma separation to target multiple medias or 'all' if it's non-specific.

Comment: ```(function($){
    // your code
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: Better and shorter `django.jQuery(function($) { // stuff })`