# How can i use angular JS in Django?? I am facing so many problems

Tags: json, django, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have created one html file in which angular js code has been located and another backend file is there. Url is working properly. but i am not able to use {{ }} in html. What is the reason for that?
   And when i am getting response from backend file is always none. But data is passing correctly in request header.

Comment: This is impossible to address. If you are using angular.js I recommend taking a look at django-rest-framework.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16014719/1189651)

Comment: I am not able to print values in ng-repeat block using {{ }}

Comment: I am also not able to get request back from views.py file. whenever i am alerting result of success is always none

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Angular JS and Django with the Django REST framework. That way you have the backend and frontend separated. Here are some links to get you started:

Getting Started with Django Rest Framework and AngularJS:
http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is because the AngularJS renderer and Django template engine share the same token for variable substitution in templates.

Use [verbatim block](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) to stop the template from Django template rendering.

Comment: I have tried that still i am not getting output..

Comment: post your code, otherwise it's hard to understand

Comment: <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
function customersController($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("/angu_json/")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
</script>

Comment: And I have send json like {"stat": "true", "result": [{"name": "krunal", "id": 2}, {"name": "umang", "id": 3}]}