# how to hide or show fields of model after clicked on choice field from admin in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class BannerAddPage(models.Model):
    BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Live'), (False, 'Pause'))
    TYPE_CHOICES = (('text', 'text'), ('image', 'image'))
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,blank=True)
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client)
    ad_type=models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES,default=True)
    ad_name=models.CharField(max_length=800,null=True,blank=True)
    ad_title=models.CharField(max_length=800,null=True,blank=True)
    ad_url1=models.URLField(max_length=800,blank=True,null=True)
    ad_banner2=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to1,blank=True,null=True)
```

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXLow.png)

I want to hide some fields after click on `ad_type(choice)` field.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use form media to add an external javascript file that will listen to the change event of the field ad_type and perform the action you need.

In this case you will need little python and lot more of js, but I think is the clean way.

To add the external js file use the [class Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#topics-forms-media), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014719/adding-a-jquery-script-to-the-django-admin-interface) to another question shows a practical example.

Than you just have to have fun with writing js code, you can use the jQuery already included in django admin.

Hope this helps