# Django - Prevent admin action to run twice

Tags: django, django-admin

My problem is simple, I have an admin action named "send email":
[image]

The problem is, the admin user can call this function twice in a row, probably by clicking "Go" many times; this causes the email to be sent multiple times. Is there a way to prevent it?

I tried to put a timeout in the end of the admin function `send_email` but it's not working: it takes 10 seconds between each users, and I have many users.

```py
def send_email(modeladmin, request, queryset):
   ...
   time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to prevent double clicking on the button.

To add javascript to your admin, you can override the admin HTML templates or adding a javascript using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014719/adding-a-jquery-script-to-the-django-admin-interface)

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#my-go-button");

let didIClickGo = false;
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!didIClickGo) {
    didIClickGo = true;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Note: on line 1, point the selector to your button.

Another option would be rate-limiting on the backend where you would save the data about the emails and whenever you call the function, you should check if you sent an email to this user in the last couple seconds maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the queryset is different from the last time to avoid calling `send_email` twice in a row:

```py
old_queryset = None

def send_email(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if self.old_queryset != queryset:
       self.old_queryset = queryset
       ... # Inserts your code here in the "if" block
```

You must define `old_queryset` as a property of the `ModelAdmin` subclass.